# Take single column from multiple CSV files and place them as new columns in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

I have multiple CSV files with the same column headers that look like this:

```
|      Date & Time      |  Rain |    Flow    |
| --------------------- | ----- | ---------- |
|    3/19/2018 12:00    |   0   |    0.51    |
|    3/19/2018 13:00    |   2   |    0.51    |
...
```

I want to take the 'Flow' column from each CSV and place them side by side according to the date. The issue I am facing is that the Date & Time for each CSV is different and I want to align the columns according to date and if there was no value for that date when I merge, I want to leave an empty space or NaN

I created a new dataframe that has a range of dates that encapsulates all the dates found in the list of CSVs, but I am unable to merge the columns accordingly.

The final dataframe would look something like

```
|      Date & Time      |    CSV 1 Flow    |    CSV 2 Flow    |    CSV 3 Flow    |
| --------------------- | ---------------- | ---------------- | ---------------- |
|    3/19/2018 12:00    |       0.51       |        NaN       |       0.34       |
|    3/19/2018 13:00    |       0.51       |        NaN       |       0.47       |
...
```

What I tried so far looks like:

```
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(pwd, "*.csv"))
range = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=45985, freq='H')
df_full = pd.DataFrame({'Date & Time': range})

for j in csv_files:
   df_full[j]=''
   df_hourly = pd.read_csv(j, usecols=['Date & Time','Flow'])
   df_merged = pd.merge(df_full, df_hourly, on='Date & Time', how='left')
```

I have gotten the code to look like:

```
range = pd.date_range('2017-01-01', periods=45985, freq='H')
df_full = pd.DataFrame({'Date & Time': range})
for filename in csv_files:
  df_full[filename] = ''
  df = pd.read_csv(filename,header=0, parse_dates=['Date & Time'], 
  usecols=['Date & Time', 'Flow'])
  df_combined = pd.merge(left=df_full,right=df, on='Date & Time', how='outer')
df_combined
```

Which gives an output DF that looks like

```
|      Date & Time      |   CSV 1 Filepath |   CSV 2 Filepath |...    | - Flow- |
| --------------------- | ---------------- | ---------------- |...    | ------- |
|    01/01/2017 00:00   |      BLANK       |      BLANK       |...    |   0.34  |
|    01/01/2017 01:00   |      BLANK       |      BLANK       |...    |   0.25  |
...
```

The entire table is blank except for the last column which is labeled 'Flow'. It seems that the script is not putting the values in the correct column.

Comment: What's the dtype of the datetime columns you're reading in? If those are misaligned with the DatetimeIndex generated by `pd.date_range(...)` you could run into issues.

Comment: Yes you were right I fixed the datetime object type and I got to the point where the output gives the skeleton of the dataframe, the column headers are the individual filenames but are blank and there is an additional column at the end that is my 'Flow' column. I believe it is merging and appending the flows to the last column instead of placing the value in the appropriate column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
df1 = pd.read_csv('example.csv', parse_dates=['Date & Time'])
df2 = pd.read_csv('example.csv', parse_dates=['Date & Time'])
df_all = df1.merge(df2, on='Date & Time', how='left')

print(df_all)
```

Output:

```
          Date & Time  Rain_x  Flow_x  Rain_y  Flow_y
0 2018-03-19 12:00:00       0    0.51       0    0.51
1 2018-03-19 13:00:00       2    0.51       2    0.51
```

Approximately your loop will be something like this:

```
csv_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(pwd, "*.csv"))

df_all = pd.read_csv(csv_files[0], parse_dates=['Date & Time'], usecols=['Date & Time','Flow'])

for file in csv_files[1:]:
    df = pd.read_csv(file, parse_dates=['Date & Time'], usecols=['Date & Time','Flow'])
    df_all = df_all.merge(df, on='Date & Time', how='left')
```

Comment: I got to the point where the output gives the skeleton of the dataframe, the column headers are the individual filenames but are blank and there is an additional column at the end that is my 'Flow' column. I believe it is merging and appending the flows to the last column instead of placing the value in the appropriate column

Comment: @mediumlondonfog check the update in the answer. Is this similar to what you are doing?

Comment: Yes that looks like what I came to now

The problem I am facing now is that the rows for the columns (filenames) are blank and there is an additional column 'Flow' at the end which has values (assuming it is for the latest iterated file). It seems to be updating that single column as it loops instead of putting the flows in the Filename columns

Comment: You should not be getting filenames in the columns. It will name same columns by adding _x, _y, _z ... to them.

Comment: Can you update your question with the current error or give more details?

Comment: Updated  with what dataframe looks like now

Comment: remove this ```df_full[filename] = ''``` and this ```how='outer'```

Comment: That gives me a DF with two columns: Date & Time and 'Flow' but with data of only the last CSV. I think it iterates through and changes a single column instead of putting the data into a new column every iteration

Comment: @mediumlondonfog You need to be updating ```df_full``` not another DF called ```df_combined```